# How to filter a json object based on req.query.params

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am using node.js and express and need to filter out the result of the array of json object

This is my array of objects

`[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Person 1",
      boughtItems: {
        item: "Shoes",
        currency: "GBP",
        cost: 200
      },
      {
        item: "Bag",
        currency: "EUR",
        cost: 300
      }
    },
      {
      id: 2,
      name: "Person 2",
      boughtItems: {
        item: "Shirt",
        currency: "GBP",
        cost: 13
      },
      {
        item: "Jacket",
        currency: "CAD",
        cost: 150
      }
      }
    ]`

by use of an endpoint ex: /continents?currency=EUR

I want to filter the results like this

`[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Person 1",
      boughtItems: 
      {
        item: "Bag",
        currency: "EUR",
        cost: 300
      }
    }
    ]`

and for ex: /continents?currency=GBP

`[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Person 1",
      boughtItems: {
        item: "Shoes",
        currency: "GBP",
        cost: 200
      }
    },
      {
      id: 2,
      name: "Person 2",
      boughtItems: {
        item: "Shirt",
        currency: "GBP",
        cost: 13
      }
      }
    ]`

should I be using filter method to do this?

Comment: 1. There's no such thing as a JSON object. 2. Use `Array.map()`

Comment: @ChrisG -- Did you mean `Array.filter()`?

Comment: @31piy I got confused because the question's first piece of code isn't a valid object literal.

Comment: @fabtree Please show us your actual output, I assume `boughtItems` is an array?

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript Array was not valid. `boughtItems` should be a list, I modified the Array, if that was truly what you meant.

*This does not mutate the original data*

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Person 1",
    boughtItems: [{
        item: "Shoes",
        currency: "GBP",
        cost: 200
      },
      {
        item: "Bag",
        currency: "EUR",
        cost: 300
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Person 2",
    boughtItems: [{
        item: "Shirt",
        currency: "GBP",
        cost: 13
      },
      {
        item: "Jacket",
        currency: "CAD",
        cost: 150
      }
    ]
  }
]

//get currency via request params
const c = "EUR";

const res = data.reduce((acc, {boughtItems, id, name}) => {
  //filter through all items, and get those that match currency
  const items = boughtItems.filter(({currency}) => currency === c);

  //if there were some that matched, create the object with the items that match
  if (items.length > 0) {
    acc.push({id,name,boughtItems: items})
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Here it is as a function:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Person 1",
    boughtItems: [{
        item: "Shoes",
        currency: "GBP",
        cost: 200
      },
      {
        item: "Bag",
        currency: "EUR",
        cost: 300
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Person 2",
    boughtItems: [{
        item: "Shirt",
        currency: "GBP",
        cost: 13
      },
      {
        item: "Jacket",
        currency: "CAD",
        cost: 150
      }
    ]
  }
]

function search(c){
    return data.reduce((acc, {boughtItems, id, name}) => {
      //filter through all items, and get those that match currency
      const items = boughtItems.filter(({currency}) => currency === c);

      //if there were some that matched, create the object with the items that match
      if (items.length > 0) {
        acc.push({id,name,boughtItems: items})
      }

      return acc;
    }, []);
}

console.log(search("EUR"));
console.log(search("GBP"));
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `filter`

```js
const array = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Person 1",
      boughtItems: [{
        item: "Shoes",
        currency: "GBP",
        cost: 200
      },
      {
        item: "Bag",
        currency: "EUR",
        cost: 300
      }]
    },
      {
      id: 2,
      name: "Person 2",
      boughtItems: [{
        item: "Shirt",
        currency: "GBP",
        cost: 13
      },
      {
        item: "Jacket",
        currency: "CAD",
        cost: 150
      }]
      }
    ];

const filterData = (array, filterValue) => array.filter(obj => (obj.boughtItems = obj.boughtItems.filter(o => o.currency === filterValue)).length);

console.log(filterData(array, 'GBP'));
```

Comment: This doesn't filter out persons without any item fitting the currency.

Comment: @ChrisG you are right, didn't notice, I have updated my answer

Comment: @ChrisG it's also single line  as yours, but mine has less code :D

Comment: Yeah, nice one :)